# Is it safe to eat expired hollandaise sauce mix

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime

I have a really old packet of McCormick Hollandaise sauce mix - it's 5 years expired.  Is it safe to use and eat?  Main ingredients are Wheat starch, maltodextrin, egg solids, soy lecithin, etc..

Comment: Isn't that what the word "expired" means in this context? "Not safe to use and eat"?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt. Not necessarily. Here in the UK we have "use by" dates which are safety based, and "best before" dates which are based on a barely detectable change in taste/texture (not necessarily for the worse). It appears that both are equivalent to "expiry" days in some places.

Comment: Same in the US (the OP is in New York and McCormick stuff is widely sold here) - expiration dates are generally "best by" except on obviously perishable things.

Comment: @ChrisH: Ah, didn't know. We might (or probably) have something similar here (NL), I just interpret every date as a "do not touch after this" date.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a powdered mix, it's still powder (not clumped) and the pack is sealed, I'd go for it. Dried foods here are most likely to have a best before date, rather than a use by (real expiry) date. If it's clumped or the packet is damaged it may have absorbed water which wouldn't be good. It's possible that the flavour will have deteriorated a little. For example, powdered egg [keeps for 5-10 years](https://www.usaemergencysupply.com/information-center/all-about/all-about-dehydrated-dairy/powdered-eggs), most foods don't have longer than a nominal year on the label.

A wet sauce mix may also keep that long if it's packed in a way equivalent to canning (i.e. sealed then cooked in the packet).

If anything seems wrong about it, avoid it.